# How create a complex Bootstrap 4 layout

Tags: layout, bootstrap-4

I just need put the box 7 below the box 6! But I can't...

All the code is below, to test in your machine please Include Bootstrap 4 from a CDN: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_get_started.asp

Ps: that is the desktop version, I don't need think about this layout in mobile version now.

Thank You!

```css
.row {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.row .row>div {
    border:solid 1px black;
    min-height:200px;
}

#box5 {
 height: 400px;
 background-color: lightgray;
}

#box6 {
 height: 200px;
}

#box7 {
 height: 200px;
}

#box8 {
 height: 600px;
 background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3">box 1</div>
                <div class="col-9">box 2</div>
   </div>
  </div>

        <div class="col-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">box 3</div>
                <div class="col-8">box 4</div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4" id="box5">box 5</div>
                <div class="col-8" id="box6">box 6</div>
                <div class="col-8" id="box7">box 7</div>
   </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12" id="box8">box 8</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#box5.col-4` and `#box6.col-8` Both elements have fully occupied a row so that `#box7` pushed out below `#box5`.

Use another `div.row` for `#box6` and `#box7` inside `div.col-8`.

```css
.row {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.row .row>div {
  border: solid 1px black;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#box5 {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#box6 {
  height: 200px;
}

#box7 {
  height: 200px;
}

#box8 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">box 1</div>
        <div class="col-9">box 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">box 3</div>
        <div class="col-8">box 4</div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4" id="box5">box 5</div>
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12" id="box6">box 6</div>
            <div class="col-12" id="box7">box 7</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" id="box8">box 8</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple solution to create that layout dynamicly with PHP.
You can use the same logic with another web language if you prefer.

```
<style>

.row {
  border: solid 1px black;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#box2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#box5 {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#box6 {
  height: 200px;
}

#box7 {
  height: 200px;
}

#box8 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.container {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#footer {
  background-color: orange;
}

</style>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<?php 
$total = 6; //from 1 to 6

?>

<?php for ($i=1; $i <= $total; $i++) :
  if ($i==1) :
?>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">box 1</div>
        <div id="box2" class="col-9">box 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php 
  endif;
  if ($i==2) :
?>
    <div class="col-9">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">box 3</div>
<?php 
endif;
if ($i==3) :
?>
   <div class="col-8">box 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4" id="box5">box 5</div>   
<?php
endif;
if ($i==4) :
?>
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12" id="box6">box 6</div>
<?php
endif;
if ($i==5) :
?>
            <div class="col-12" id="box7">box 7</div>
          </div>
<?php 
endif;
if ($i==6) : 
 ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" id="box8">box 8</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php 
endif;
endfor;

if ($total == 1) { echo '</div></div></div></div>'; }
if ($total == 2) { echo '</div></div></div></div></div></div>'; }
if ($total == 3) { echo '</div></div></div></div></div></div>'; }
if ($total == 4) { echo '</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>'; }
if ($total == 5) { echo '</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>'; }


?>

<div class="container-fluid" id="footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```